# My and Linda's or Mine and Linda's?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, word-order, possessives

How do you use possessive pronouns in cases where there are multiple "owners" and "objects" in question? For example would it be:

"I've included my and Linda's suggestions in the file"

or

"I've included mine and Linda's suggestions in the file" ?

Also, should I always include "both" before the first possessive pronoun in the sentence and what should be the listing order: me first or Linda first?

Comment: "Our suggestions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be "I have included Linda's and my suggestions in the file."

The trick is to simplify. Separately you would write:

"I have included my suggestions in the file."

and

"I have included Linda's suggestions in the file."

Since the same rules apply in combination, either "my and Linda's", or "Linda's and my" are correct. "Both" is optional before the first term and equally correct.

Which sounds or looks better is a matter of taste.