# "He is a friend of Tom and mine" "He is my and Tom's friend"

Tags: possessives, double-possessive

I have read all the related Q&A I could find on here, but there didn't seem to be one that answers my question exactly. There was one question that was related, but I don't think this would be a duplicate, so here goes nothing:

> This is Brian. He is a friend of mine and Tom's (or: he is a friend of Tom's and mine/he is a friend of Tom and mine)

I got stuck writing this line because "a friend of Tom's and mine" sounds best to my ear but I don't trust my ear. Are the other options correct?

> This is Brian. He is Tom's and my friend. (or: he is my and Tom's friend/he is Tom and my friend)

With this sentence, "he is Tom's and my friend" and "he is my and Tom's friend" sound fine, but I am not entirely sure either.

Comment: Can you add the links to at least two questions that you consulted?

Comment: @Mari-LouA That one only considers oblique genitives, this one is considers the oblique genitive as well as both the  *s*-genitive and the normal *of*-genitive.

Comment: There are several 'Related' question on the right here. I suggest "He is Tom's friend and mine."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner) Also [My and Linda's or Mine and Linda's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162590/my-and-lindas-or-mine-and-lindas), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Those aren't obliques genitives! [oblique genitive = *the X of Y's*, as opposed to *Y's X* or *the X of Y*]

Comment: @WeatherVane - Or *he is friends with both Tom and me.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Seen it and that's the one I said was related. If you have read my question carefully I don't believe you could say it's a duplicate. Does the answer there address this: "He is Tom's and my friend"?

Comment: "There was one question that was related," but with no link and no question title. In any case, I put the link up in the comments :)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. how is one of  the possible solutions presented by the OP: **Z is a friend of X's and mine** different from this post?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It isn't, but it's only *one* of the suggestions they are weighing up.